# Use numpy with Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I want to create .so file from python and execute the .so file in C.
To do it I used cython to convert .pyx to .so

```
## print_me.pyx
cimport numpy as cnp
import  numpy as np
cimport cython
cpdef public char* print_me(f):
    # I know this numpy line does nothing
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.complex128_t, ndim=3] a = np.zeros((3,3,3), dtype=np.complex128)
    return f
```

Then I used setup.py to actually convert .pyx to .so

```
## setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("print_me.pyx"),
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
)
```

By running the following command line, I was able to create .so file

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

When I tried to run so file using the following C code, I got a Segmentation Fault.

```
/* toloadso.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

int main(void)
{
    // define function
    void *handle;
    char* (*print_me)(PyObject*);
    char *error;

    PyObject* filename = PyString_FromString("hello");

    // load so file
    handle = dlopen("./print_me.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    dlerror();

    // get function handler from so file
    print_me = (char* (*)(PyObject*))dlsym(handle, "print_me");

    // check if handler got error
    error = dlerror();
    if (error != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // execute loaded function
    printf("%s\n", (char*)(*print_me)(filename));
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I compiled this .c file with following command:

```
gcc -fPIC -I/usr/include/ -o toloadso toloadso.c -lpython2.7 -ldl
(It compiled without error or warning)
```

When I tried to run this code, I got a segmentation Fault

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./toloadso
Segmentation fault
```

If I comment out the following line in print_me.pyx

```
cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.complex128_t, ndim=3] a = np.zeros((3,3,3), dtype=np.complex128)
```

My C code runs without error, but once I uncomment this line, it does not work.
I think that trying to use numpy in cython generates an error somehow.

How can I fix it??
I thank you so much for your reply

Comment: Does `print_me.so` work as a Python import?

Comment: Yes it works on python. but when I call the function  by loading .so file from c file, it does not work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must [initialize the numpy C API by calling `import_array()`](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/tutorials-numpy#c-api-initialization).

Add this line to your cython file:

```
cnp.import_array()
```

And as pointed out by @user4815162342 and @DavidW in the comments, you must call [`Py_Initialize()` and `Py_Finalize()` in `main()`](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#public-declarations).

Comment: Also, `Py_Initialize()` is missing in `main()`!

Comment: cnp.import_array() does not work :( it still gives me Segmentation Fault.

Comment: I don't think Py_Initialize() is needed. because in C file, I am just calling .so file. that is all my c file does.

Comment: @jinki Python objects are created and used (e.g. PyString_FromString and a numpy array) so you _do_ need to initialize Python. There's some [documenation on how to do this](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c) that you should read.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help first. I could get something useful information, even though that could not directly solve my problem.

By referring to others advice,
rather than calling print_me function from .so file, I decided to call directly from C. This is what I did.

```
# print_me.pyx
import  numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()

cdef public char* print_me(f):
    cdef int[2][4] ll = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5,6,7,8]]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=2] nll = np.zeros((4, 6), dtype=np.int)
    print nll
    nll += 1
    print nll
    return f + str(ll[1][0])
```

This is my .c file

```
// main.c
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
#include "print_me.h"

int main()
{
    // initialize python
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* filename = PyString_FromString("hello");
    initsquare_number();
    //initprint_me();

    // call python-oriented function
    printf("%s\n", print_me(filename));

    // finalize python
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled then as follows

```
# to generate print_me.c and print_me.h
cython print_me.pyx

# to build main.c and print_me.c into main.o and print_me.o
cc -c main.c print_me.c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# to linke .o files
cc -lpython2.7 -ldl main.o print_me.o -o main

# execute main
./main
```

This results the following

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]]
hello5
```

Thank you for all of your help again!! :)